Node.js - [CRUD] update
I created a menu-edit.pug to show my edit form, hopefully users click the menu link, jumping to this edit page, and make some updates, when submit the form, the updated value will be stored and redirect to the menu page.
My code: edit page is ready, but there's something wrong with my edit/submit, when I submit my updated data on the browser, it will created a new link instead of overwriting on the existing one.
menu-edit page
block layout-content
    div.content
        h1.page-title Edit menu link
        //- /admin/menu/edit/submit will be the location where the form data is submitted to
        form(method="post", action="/admin/menu/edit/submit")
            input(type="hidden", name="linkId", value=editLink._id)
            div 
                label(for="wgt") Weight: 
                input(type="number", id="wgt", name="weight", value=editLink.weight)
            div 
                label(for="href") URI: 
                input(type="text", id="href", name="path", value=editLink.path)
            div 
                label(for="link-name") Link text: 
                input(type="text", id="link-name", name="name", value=editLink.name)
            button(type="submit") Update link

My index.js is like the below:
app.get("/admin/menu/edit", async (request, response) => {
  if (request.query.linkId) {
    let linkToEdit = await getSingleLink(request.query.linkId);
    let links = await getLinks();
    response.render("menu-edit", { title: "Edit menu link", menu: links, editLink: linkToEdit });
  }
  else {
    response.redirect("/admin/menu");
  }
});

app.post("/admin/menu/edit/submit", async (request, response) => {
  let id = request.query.linkId; 
  let idFilter = { _id: new ObjectId(id)};
  let link = {
      weight: parseInt(request.body.weight),
      path: request.body.path,
      name: request.body.name
  };
  await editLink(idFilter, link);
  response.redirect("/admin/menu");
})

async function getSingleLink(id) {
  db = await connection();
  const editId = { _id: new ObjectId(id) };
  const result = await db.collection("menuLinks").findOne(editId);
  return result;
}

async function editLink(filter, link) {
  db = await connection();
  const options = { upsert: true };
  // Specify the update to set a value for the link field
  let updateLink = {
    $set: {
    weight: link.weight,
    path: link.path,
    name: link.name
    }
};
  let result = await db.collection("menuLinks").updateOne(filter, updateLink, options);
  // Print the number of matching and modified documents
  // https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/usage-examples/updateOne/#std-label-node-usage-updateone
  console.log(
    `${result.matchedCount} document(s) matched the filter, updated ${result.modifiedCount} document(s)`,
  );
}

